# Is it possible to use the same database for 3 different Discovery Services?

Tags: web8, discovery-service

Is it possible to use the same database for 3 different Discovery Services on the same server?

I Hope it registers all capabilities configured in 3 different Discovery Services, when I run `discovery-registrations` jar.

Answer (score 6):

It's not I'm afraid.

If your Discovery Services (and associated Microservices) were on three separate servers, then you could use the 'localhost' workaround described by Quirijn here: 
[USING SDL’S MICROSERVICES IN A WEB FARM](http://blog.trivident.com/using-sdls-microservices-in-a-web-farm/)

However, the URL of the Content Service is stored in the Discovery Database just once  (i.e. the last one that was registered), so you won't be able to differentiate them.

Comment: I'm using different ports for each discovery service e.g. http://<servername>:8088

Comment: Although your Discovery Services (and presumably Content Services) will all use separate ports, the Discovery Database will only store the URL of one of your Content Services (i.e. the last one that was registered). This will result in all three of your Discovery Services pointing at the one Content Service when they start up. Unfortunately, I think you're going to need three Discovery Databases in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Actually I don't want to increase number of databases so want to register all discovery services capabilities into single database. & later use this discovery for deployer capability

Comment: Yes...Discovery DB can contain only one entry for each Capability at any point of time. If registered again pointing to same DB, it will be overwritten.

Comment: As i have multiple deployers, so i have to create multiple discovery services. Can you guide me to the script to create new discovery database? Is database structure similar to broker DB ?

Comment: The structure is identical to the Broker database. However it's recommended to keep them separate to avoid mixing (published) content and configuration. Here is the page in the online docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-654563D2-F38B-43C9-851C-0C1104FBA2AA